# Changing the SharePoint List names and column names according to the language chosen by the user

Tags: mui

I have a list named as Student

[image]

Now I make my website multilingual. Is there any option to show the list name and columns as below if I choose the language as arabic

[image]

I know the list name is a constant string entered by the user and it cannot be translated when the language of the site is changed. But I read in this article ([How to display column names in several languages in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30226/how-to-display-column-names-in-several-languages-in-sharepoint)) that using the strings referred in the Resource file, it is achievable. So I created 3 resource files in 14/Resources and using the following format, I named the SharePoint List and columns with the 
strings I defined in the Resource files.

($Resources:Resourcefilename,stringid;)

But this did not work for me. Is there any out of the box way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve what you're looking for the following way: If your SharePoint site supports the target language, so default controls are named correctly, you can go into list and field settings and simply change the title. This will not change the title for every language, but rather only the current language.

If this doesn't feel like the right solution for you and if you're familiar with PowerShell you could something like shown in this link:

[Localization using PowerShell](https://chamindasomathilaka.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/add-quick-launch-navigation-entries-together-with-localization-text-using-powershell/)

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for.